# How to add new row as group total using Data Stage

Tags: datastage

I have input data like below

`CovNo  type       Price

10     med tot    110
10     med tot    120
10     dent tot   140
20     med tot    110
20     dent tot   130
20     med tot    120`


How can i generate the output data like below

`CovNo type       Price

10    med tot    110
10    med tot    120
10    dent tot   140
10    Group tot  370
20    med tot    110
20    dent tot   130
20    med tot    120
20    Group tot  360`


Shall i know the logic to implement the above scenario in Datastage.

Thanks in advance,
Shanmugam

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the source of your data one way could be to solve it with SQL if your source is a table.

If you want or need to do it in DataStage only you could fork your data using a copy stage and have one output fed into an aggregtor stage where you calculate the sums per group. The other output is of the copy is then combined with the results of the aggregator with a funnel stage (which behaves like a union in SQL). That's it.

Answer (score 0):

For the above example, we could achieve it in transformer using the SaveInputRecord() and GetSavedInputRecord() and LastRowInGroup() functions.

IBM has provided a [perfect example](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.parjob.dev.doc/topics/specifyingaloopexample4.html) for this type of scenario.

**Note:** The performance would be impacted if the data is huge as it uses cache memory. So if your data is huge, then better to split the source and perform a join after the aggregation or you could easily do it using sql if you source is a database.